# How hide component from another component start render through route on react

Tags: reactjs

I would like to hide a component when another component is routing

for more specific, i have a fixed bottom nav that i want to hide when a component is been route by user, in this case its a comment box

My first option was trying on the parent component with browserhistory and history.listen, and componning a string with math.params for get a match between, and this change the state of parent, witch will hide the bottomnav, and the code wrote was trying through a cyclelife passing props, but nothing, anyone can help me please?

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showBottomNav: true
    }
    this.hideBottomNav = this.hideBottomNav.bind(this)
  }

  hideBottomNav= () => {
    this.setState({
      showBottomNav: false

    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/wars' exact component={Tournament} />
          <Route path='/shop' exact component={Shop} />
          <Route path='/library' exact component={Library} />
          <Route 
            path='/:id' 
            exact 
            render={ props => <ExpandedPost {...props} parentMethod={() => this.hideBottomNav()} />} 
            />
        </Switch>
        <BottomNav />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the children Component

```
export default function PostReview(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
      props.parentMethod()
    },[props])

    return (

      <div>....
```

Comment: Change `parentMethod={() => this.hideBottomNav()}` to `parentMethod={this.hideBottomNav}`